# Auto-scrolling in jQuery.scrollTo / jQuery.serialScroll works like crazy

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval, scrollto, serialscroll

I used the following tutorial to make a parallax content slider for my webiste: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/

I got it working nicely, but wanted to add auto-scrolling functionality. I did it by adding jQuery.serialScroll and using setInterval but it works like crazy now. I guess the slider is now going through every 3 slides every 5 seconds, instead of 1 slide per 5 second. I have no idea how to make it working properly.

Here is a part of my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1 id="logo">Testing slider</h1>
</div>
<!-- end logo -->

<div id="slider">
    <div id="background">
        <div id="bg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end slide background -->

    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="mask">
            <li id="box1" class="box">
                <a name="box1"><img src="images/slide1.png"></a>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inner">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- end box1 -->

            <li id="box2" class="box">
                <a name="box2"><img src="images/slide2.png"></a>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inner">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- end box2 -->

            <li id="box3" class="box">
                <a name="box3"><img src="images/slide3.png"></a>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inner">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- end box3 -->

        </ul>
        <!-- end mask -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- end Slider -->

<div id="content">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="menuitem">
            <li><a href="#box1" class="slide_next"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#box2" class="slide_next"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#box3" class="slide_next"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end menu -->

</div>
<!-- end content -->
```

And here is the troubling JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a.slide_next').click(function () {  
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#background', '0px', '50px', '100px')
        $('a.slide_next').removeClass('selected');  
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;  
    }); 
});

        setInterval(function() {$('a.slide_next').click()}, 5000);  

function setPosition(check, div, p1, p2, p3) {
if(check==='#box1')
    {           $(div).scrollTo(p1, 800);       }
else if(check==='#box2')
    {           $(div).scrollTo(p2, 800);       }
else
    {           $(div).scrollTo(p3, 800);       }
};  



</script>
```

Please, anyone has any idea how to get it working the way it should be (1 slide each 5 sec)?

PS. Please be nice, I'm new in the field ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're triggering the click event on ALL 3 of your "slide next" links every 5 seconds, so it's going wappy trying to carry out your onclick code for each slide.

What you could do is something like this:

```
//set a global var to keep track of the slide we're on
window.slide = 1
function nextSlide(){
   //increase window.slide by 1 (to go to the next slide), 
   //or if it is 3 return to the first slide
   window.slide == 3 ? window.slide = 1 : window.slide++;
   //trigger click event on the NEXT slide only
   $('a[href=#box'+window.slide+']').click()
}
setInterval(nextSlide,5000);
```

This way every 5 seconds the click event on the link to move to the NEXT slide will be triggered (and not all of them).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works fine. Many thanks!

However, autoscrolling works kind of independently from scrolling using links with "slide_next" class.